# Use a microwave motor to power LEDs

Tags: motor, ac, dc, generator, converter

I have an AC motor that came from a microwave turntable on the back it says 120v 2w 6rpm.  I would like to use it as means to generate some electricity.  I have a full wave bridge rectifier to convert it to DC.

What is the simplest means to convert it to an usable voltage? A small wall transformer?

Any efficient leds to match the output once i step it down?

Comment: There are many different types of motors capable of running on AC, which present different challenges for repurposing as a  generator.  To get a meaningful answer you will need to be more specific.

Comment: Added more details on motor.  Could you be more specific on what specific details would get me a more specific answer @ChrisStratton I am a beginner or hobbyist

Comment: Start by reading up on the different types of AC motors and then identify which sort you have.

Comment: A "6 rpm" motor sounds like a timing motor which is actually a faster synchronous motor assembled to a gearbox you probably won't be able to backdrive. This is probably not the right part for your task.

Comment: got suggestions on a motor for the task that ins't ridiculously expensive.  close to free would be nice for a first attempt on this. @ChrisStratton

Comment: You'd probably be better off with a small permanent magnet DC motor, but read some of the wind power hobby sites for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I've used one of those motors as a generator for one of my pet projects. They can provide a decent voltage at low RPMs, however these are AC synchronous machines which run at a speed much higher than 6RPM (determined by its physical construction, usually 1500RPM) so there is a gearbox in there with a high gearing ratio, which will require a lot of torque on the output shaft to generate anything useful... Since they're made out of plastic, you might damage them; so this needs to be tested. I wouldn't expect a high lifetime from one of these things even if it works.

Anyway, for your actual problem, it depends on how you are inputting your mechanical energy: can it be considered to be turning your generator at a constant speed? Then you could get away with using a resistor: since your LEDs are not a variable load, you can calculate a resistance value that will work. However, the mechanical energy required will be increased for the same load, since most of it will be lost in the heating of the resistor. 
If the source is variable, for example if it's hand-cranked, you need to use a voltage regulator to absorb the voltage variations and produce a solid constant voltage.

Either way, the ripple of a single phase AC waveform once full-wave rectified is the peak voltage of the waveform (i.e. it drops right down to 0V every 20ms), so you'll need to add a capacitor to hold the voltage above the minimum input voltage of the voltage regulator if you're using one, or above whichever value will make your LEDs too dim if you are using a resistor. OR you consider 100Hz (twice mains frequency, because of the full bridge rectifier) is enough to take advantage of the retinal persistance, and you design the resistor for the average value, making sure the peak voltage will not damage your LEDs because of the increased current. This way, no need for a capacitor.

Connecting a wall wart directly to the motor is similar to the voltage regulator approach, so there will be a speed under which your output will drop.

Bottom line: test it!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is a resistor. The LEDs need one anyway to limit current flow. I'm not sure how many volts your motor will produce but cut of 1.4V of the output due to the silicon diodes in your rectifier and change the resistor accordingly. You might want to add a capacitor (sorry i cant give values, I don't know the current or voltage) to reduce the effect of voltage spikes/dips (no one likes flickering LEDs). A wall transformer would also work but is also far more expensive than a resistor, and to power led a resistor is good enough. As for the LEDs, most will work if your trying just to power one, but if your trying to use several of them, you may need to look into that more (sorry for lack of specific instruction I will need more information to give that).

Answer (score 0):

For your first attempt to make a small generator demonstration, the easiest and least expensive motor to use as a generator would be a small battery operated motor. The type of motor used in inexpensive battery-operated toys is a permanent-magnet DC motor with brushes. It will generate DC by simply turning the shaft. It will probably not be very difficult to turn the shaft fast enough to light an LED. A toy that is no longer useful because the plastic parts are broken is likely to contain a useable motor.